# WP8 How to redirect app to system app on Startup?

Tags: c#

I want to create an app similar to those Wi-Fi tile things that when you tap it, it immediately goes to Wi-Fi settings, but what I want is that when the app is installed and started, it is immediately redirected. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can put redirect (e.g. LaunchUriAsync() call) to the very start of your app and then exit. But anyway you have to launch your app first and it won't feel like redirecting, e.g. user may notice splash screen etc.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm a noob at this

Comment: You actually have to know name of URI scheme (e.g. 'skype:') of the app you want to redirect to. Here is example of how to launch WP8 built-in apps: http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2013/01/how-to-launch-wp8-settings-page.html